# Custom Route constraint in Orchard CMS not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, orchardcms

I am trying to setup a custom route in Orchard CMS with the intention of catching 'Users' names in the URL so that they may view their profile on the front-end; currently their profile is accessible via:

http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Orc/Profile?username=Terry

What I wish to replicate is what nearly all sites do, and that is, have such a page accessible simply via:

http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/Orc/Profile/Terry

My code is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Orchard;
using Orchard.Mvc.Routes;
using Orchard.Security;

namespace PP.Orc.Routes
{
public class ProfileRoutes : IRouteProvider {
    private static readonly IMembershipService _membershipService;
    private static readonly IOrchardServices _orchardServices;

    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
        return new[] {

            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 5,
                Route = new Route(
                    "Profile/{username}",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "PP.Orc"},
                        {"controller", "Profile"},
                        {"action", "Index"},
                        //{"username", new UserNameConstraint() }//UrlParameter.Optional }
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"username",  new UserNameConstraint()}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "PP.Orc"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())

            }
        };
    }

    public class UserNameConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            // Get the username from the url
            var username = values["username"].ToString().ToLower();
            // Check for a match (assumes case insensitive)
            IUser user = _membershipService.GetUser(username);

            if (user == null || !_orchardServices.Authorizer.Authorize(Permissions.ViewProfiles, user, null))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
}
```

However, when attempting the desired URL - all I receive is:

**Server Error in '/OrchardLocal' Application.
The resource cannot be found.**

Clearly I am missing some element i'm not aware of, or don't fully grasp how to correctly implement a route in the first place?

---

**UPDATE**

So I've discovered what works - but am at a loss as to why it matters - and why other descriptors work, as I originally had it, and continue to do so?

Basically, adding **PP/Profile/{username}** makes it operable...

However, for brevity sakes, I originally neglected two other descriptors prior the one in question (which both worked):

```
           new RouteDescriptor {
               Priority = 7,
               Route = new Route(
                   "Profile/Register",
                   new RouteValueDictionary {
                       {"area", "PP.Orc"},
                       {"controller", "Profile"},
                       {"action", "Register"}
                   },
                   new RouteValueDictionary (),
                   new RouteValueDictionary {
                       {"area", "PP.Orc"}
                   },
                   new MvcRouteHandler())
            },
            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 6,
                Route = new Route(
                    "Profile/Edit",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "PP.Orc"},
                        {"controller", "Profile"},
                        {"action", "Edit"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary (),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "PP.Orc"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())

            },
```

...so I dont know why they work without the 'PP', yet the USERNAME descriptor doesnt?

Comment: Check the Priority and see if it needs to be raised.

Comment: Can you debug your match function?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts guys, see my update ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you put Profile/{username} will be with the ? caracter, like the first case, try putting Profile/username